# Проблема с Entity Framework и WPF (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией.
Программа запущена. Меняю данные в таблице wrk_Device_Value НЕ из программы.
Далее запускаю метод для заполнения коллекции, в котором содержится указанная ниже строка.
Запрос к БД выполняется (смотрю через Profiler), при этом данные в коллекции остаются прежними.

В чем может быть ошибка?

```
ValuesList = new ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value>
            (_dataContext.wrk_Device_Value.Where(d => d.ID_Device == device.ID_Device).ToList());
```

Comment: _"Меняю данные в таблице wrk_Device_Value НЕ из программы"_ -- а сохраняете изменения?

Comment: @Stack, да, запрос, считанный профайлером, проверяю - данные новые, но коллекция не обновляется

Comment: В рамках сессии EF скорее всего данные получаются один раз, потом уже работа идёт с кешем. Если вам надо каждый раз получать данные из таблицы явно - открывайте новую сессию на каждый чих. С EF не работал, прикидываю по ситуации.

Comment: Хм.. А стратегия обновления какая?

Comment: @Qwertiy я пока новичок в этом. Что имеется ввиду? Если то, как я изменяю данные в таблице, то просто через SQL Man. Studio меняю значение в таблице.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, в EF можно задать то, как будут обновляться данные. Типа расстановки блокировок, проверки на изменение и т. д. Возможно, оно как-то связано с происходящим.

Answer (score 0):

При пересоздании коллекции нужно вручную вызывать `RaisePropertyChanged("ValuesList")`, или объявлять `ValuesList` например так:

```
private ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value> _valuesList;
public ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value> ValuesList
{
   get { return _valuesList; }
   set
   {
      if (_valuesList == value) return;
      _valuesList = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("ValuesList");
   }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло. Данные по-прежнему старые

Comment: Вынесите код `_dataContext.wrk_Device_Value.Where(d => d.ID_Device == device.ID_Device).ToList()` в отдельную переменную и в режиме отладки посмотрите содержимое, действительно ли приходят не те данные, или проблема с отображением.

Comment: Проверил. В переменную записываются старые данные, которые подгружаются при запуске программы.

Comment: Проблема, видимо, с модельным классом. Если меняю значение одного поля в таблице через MSSQL и обновляю коллекцию - данные в коллекции остаются прежними. А при удалении строки в таблице, данные в коллекции обновляются. В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Вам действительно стоит посмотреть в сторону кэширования. Где-то оно у вас происходит, и где, не зная проекта, предугадать довольно сложно.

Comment: Возможно, [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564265/entity-framework-refresh-objects-from-database) топик вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Проблема, оказывается, в самом EF. По умолчанию параметр MergeOptions установлен в AppendOnly, поэтому я вижу только добавленные данные. Можно его поменять на OverwriteChanges, но, насколько я понял, это не является хорошей практикой. Решил выполнять запрос, открывая и закрывая новый контекст.